# Typescript: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'

Tags: typescript

In my React Native app, I get the following error:

```
error TS7015: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

...     const result = resultArray[key];
```

And this is the code TypeScript is complaining about:

```
export interface Person {
  name: string;
  number: string;
}

export interface PersonResults {
  [key: string]: Person;
}
const resultArray: PersonResults[] = [];

const keys = Object.keys(resultArray).forEach(key => {
  const result = resultArray[key]; // here the error occurs
  const name = Object.values(result)[0].name;
  namesArray.push(name);
});
```

The content of resultArray is as follows:

```
resultarray:  [{"0": {"name": "john", "number": "2134"}}, {"1": {"name": "mary", "number": "85475"}}]
```

So I have an array with multiple entries and I would like to get the `name` value of every entry. I understand that `key` here is always a string, and that a string can not be used as index. Instead, it should be a number. But how do i do that?

I tried to cast key into a number, but that workaround seems so ugly to me. And I think `keyof` can not be used in this case, because I'm not referencing an interface, right?

Comment: add contents of result array ...

Comment: why not `resultArray.forEach(v => { namesArray.push(v.name) })` ? I might be missing something, but I think you should also add the structure of the resultArray in the question :)

Comment: @zmf Thank you, please see my edited post.

Comment: @RuntimeError try `resultArray.forEach(v => {
    console.log(v[resultArray.indexOf(v)].name)
});`

Comment: @zmf Thank you sooooooooo much, it works! You're the best!